# Need to build a drag drop form designer in browser - Is AngularJS the right framerwork for this kind of a requirement

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, drag-and-drop, single-page-application

My requirement is a build a web form designer in a browser - just like how [Zoho Creator](http://creator.zoho.com) (or something similar to other browser based designer tools like [proto.io](http://proto.io), [protoshare](http://www.protoshare.com/), [gomockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/), [lucidcharts](https://www.lucidchart.com) etc).
Have a tool box/palate on one side, a canvas and a properties box that always shows the properties of the selected control.

I definitely don't think that using JQuery and working with DOM elements will give a scalable solution like these (proto.io, lucidchart etc.). After numerous trials, I feel that AngularJS is the way to go, but it does not have native support for drag-drop and hence I want inputs from community members like you may have more experience with AngularJS on whether what I am setting out to do, is Angularjs the right framework to use for this kind of a solution?

See screens shots of tools like [Proto.io](http://proto.io) - something very similar to what I am setting out to build. Just that my palate will contain form controls like textbox, label etc which I will drag and drop on the canvas instead of the shapes that proto.io has.

[image]

Comment: Hi Moiz
Did you find any oprnsource samples similar to prot.io.
I want to do a similar job.

Comment: Try out the graphic libraries pointed out by the other  gentleman on this question. They are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is fine. But the main idea of these kind of frameworks like Angular, Dojo, backbone is to structure your application with a specific designed pattern.Hence getting benefit from that pattern. And Angular will help you construct your app into MV* pattern. i may think what you need now is a graph library that support things with canvas , drag-drop , palettes, templates, overview, etc. Some may be useful are [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/), [MxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/),[Draw2D](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/), [Data-driven Documents](http://d3js.org/), [gojs](http://www.gojs.net/latest/index.html), [mindfusion](http://www.mindfusion.eu/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. They definitely seem to be promising. I will try these out.

Answer (score 0):

Draw2D supports Angular as well. The lib has a boilerplate app whichs shows 
how to use the draw2d stuff in combination with angluar.

The examples shows how to structure your app with Controller, Factories and  two way 
data binding.

I think you can use the draw2d boilderplate with any other DragDrop lib. It's just
a pattern how to integrate a third party lib into angular.

Angular has many hooks and pattern which supports any kind of lib

Greetings

Andreas